# Changing one table cell which affects another cell

Tags: jquery, html-table, this

How do I change one drink to another, so that the cost reflects that change in the next cell?

For example:  I selected a drink, click "Place Order" button, click on the "edit" button.  In the "Drink Type" cell, I change from tea to coke: the drink cost cell should change from: $2.25 to $2.50, but it stays the same.

As far as I know everything looks right in my code, and I cannot figure out why it does not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/9d7ee9fr/7/

I would appreciate any suggestions:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
        Customer's Information
        </legend>
<br><br> 

Drink Order:    
<!--asks for coffee type-->
<select name="drinkType" id="drinkType">
    <option value="#">Select Drink</option>
    <option value="0">Tea  $2.25</option>
    <option value="1">Coke  $2.50</option>
    <option value="2">Coffee  $2.75</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="button" id="placeOrderBtn" value="Place Order">    
<br><br>

</fieldset>
</form>
<br>   
<table id = "receiptOrders">  
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Number</th>
            <th>Drink Type</th>
            <th>Drink Cost</th>
            <th>Edit/Save</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
</main>
</div><!-- end .container -->
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
"use strict";

// Global Variables
var amt = 0; 
var itemNumber; // for receipt purposes

// arrays
var drinkCosts = [2.25, 2.50, 2.75]; // costs of each drink type
var drinkTypeHolder =[]; // holds each customer's name
var drinkCostHolder = []; // holds each customer's subtotal
var drink;

// ready event: short way
$(function() {    
    // calculates total cost
    $("#placeOrderBtn").click(function() {
        if ($("#drinkType").val() == "#") {
            alert ("Please select a drink type");
        } else {
        drink = parseInt($("#drinkType").val()); // gets id: drinkType value from HTML page

        //calls the function 
        var drinkCost = drinkAmt(drink);
        drinkCost = parseFloat(drinkCost);
        $("#drinkCost").val(drinkCost.toFixed(2)); 

        var drinkName = drinkType(drink);
        var totalList = 0; 

        drinkTypeHolder.push(drinkName); // adds drink type name

        drinkCostHolder.push(drinkCost); // adds subtotal cost

        // i retrieves each element from the array
       for (var i = 0; i < drinkTypeHolder.length; i++) { 
           totalList = "<tr><td></td><td class='editableText'>" + drinkTypeHolder[i] + "</td><td>" + drinkCostHolder[i] + "</td><td><input type='button' value='Edit' class='editBtn'><input type='button' value='Save' class='saveBtn'></td></tr>";    
        }

    $("#receiptOrders > tbody").append(totalList); // table: tbody: children
    }

// edits information
$(".editBtn").click(function() { 
    $(this).hide(); // hides edit button
    $(this).next(".saveBtn").show(); // displays save button

    // finding cells in the row of the selected edit button, but ignoring item number, and last item
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function() {
        $("td:first-child").prop("contenteditable", false); // makes item number not editable
        $(".editBt, .saveBtn").prop("contenteditable", false); // makes item number not editable
        $("tr").not(this).prop("contenteditable", false); 
        $(this).prop("contenteditable", true);

        $("td:first-child, .editBt, .saveBtn").css({"backgroundColor": "#fff"});
        $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "#c4c7c6"}); 
});
});

// There is no change event on contenteditable element.
// Input event fires on a contenteditable editor when its contents are changed 
    $("td:nth-child(2)").on("input",function(){
        if ($(this).text() == "Tea" || $(this).text() == "tea") {
            $(this).next("td").html("2.25");
            $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "red"}); // for test purposes
        } else if ($(this).text() == "Coke" || $(this).text() == "coke") {
            $(this).next("td").html("2.50"); 
            $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "blue"}); // for test purposes
        } else if ($(this).text() == "Coffee" || $(this).text() == "coffee") {
            $(this).next("td").html("2.75"); 
            $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "pink"}); // for test purposes
    }
 });

// saves information
$(".saveBtn").click(function() {
    $(this).hide(); // hides save button
    $(this).prev(".editBtn").show(); // displays edit button
    $(this).prop("contenteditable", false);
    $("td").not(this).prop("contenteditable", false); 

    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function() {
        $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "#fff"});
    });

    });
    }); // end places order click

}); // end of ready event handler

// matches each drink type to each price
// gets amount
var drinkAmt = function(inDrink) {
    var amt = 0;
    switch(inDrink) {
    case 0:
      amt = drinkCosts[0]; // Tea
      break;
    case 1:
      amt = drinkCosts[1]; // Coke  
      break;
    case 2:
      amt = drinkCosts[2]; // Coffee
      break;
}
    return amt;
};

var drinkType = function(inDrink) {
    switch(inDrink) {
    case 0:
            return "Tea"; // Tea
            break;
    case 1:
           return "Coke"; // Coke  
           break;
    case 2:
           return "Coffee"; // Coffee
           break;
}
};
```

Comment: Is this a homework or real stuff? If it's not a homework, It doesn't make much sense. Instead of `Place order` should be `Add` or something like that... As well as there should be an option to `Remove` the item. `Place order` is final step... if order is placed, you should not be able to edit it. And... your code adds infinite `OnChange` events... every time you click `Edit`, it adds a new one. And... you have to write down the name of product? what if you will write for example `Juice`?

Comment: Another thing is that `contenteditable` element has no `OnChange` event. It's called `input`. `$('<content_editable_element>').on('input', ...` <-- doesn't work in IE.

Comment: I am currently taking a class. It is an assignment, however, I am trying to go beyond the assigment so I can learn more.  I already have a remove the item, but I did not include it.  The reason is because I was reading the instructions and it mentions: "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem."  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... first of all you are doing it wrong...

There is no `change` event on `contenteditable` element. You can change it to `keydown` or use `.on('input',function())` ... like this:

```
$("td:nth-child(2)").keydown(function(){ ...
```

or

```
$("td:nth-child(2)").on('input',function(){ ...
```

Please note that first solution won't work if you will copy paste a text into it with a mouse right click menu.

---

Second thing is that if you are adding new event every time `Edit` button is clicked, it stacks... so after clicking `Edit`, `Save`, `Edit`, `Save`, `Edit`, `Save` ... there will be 3 events (same events) binded. And will be triggered 3 times. Thats a memory leak. You need to remove that event when clicking `Save` button...

In first case, it  would be:

```
$("td:nth-child(2)").unbind('keypress');
```

In second case, it would be:

```
$("td:nth-child(2)").off('input');
```

---

Another thing is that you need to understand is how `jQuery` selectors work and what `.eq()` does. From your example, you don't seem to understand that...

Please read [this document](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Basically it selects an element from element set. But in your case `$("td:nth-child(2)")` is not a set, but single element. So calling `.eq(2)` on it makes totally no sense, as there is no 2nd element in that set.

In your code:

```
     $("td:nth-child(2)").change(function(){ 
        if ($(this).eq(2) == "Tea" || "tea") {
            $(this).eq(3).html(2.25);
        } 
     ...
```

`$("td:nth-child(2)")` is an element that contains product name, so referring to it should simply be `$(this)`, not `$(this).eq(2)`. Other thing is that you can't compare element to string, like you do in `$(this).eq(2) == "Tea"` ... you need to use `$(this).text()` to get the text of that element. So it should be:

```
if ($(this).text() == "Tea" || "tea") { ...
```

Ok. But how to select the price field then? I already mentioned that `$(this).eq(3).html(2.25);` makes totally no sense - as `$(this)` is one element, not set of elements. To select next `td` element, you should use `.next('td')`:

```
     $("td:nth-child(2)").change(function(){ 
        if ($(this).text() == "Tea" || "tea") {
            $(this).next('td').html("2.25"); // <-- this supposed to be a string, not float, so we are using double or single quotas.
        } 
     ...
```

Well... that would be it. Damn, I should be a teacher. Have fun learning!

Comment: Well first of all, thank you professor :)   
You mentioned that: "...after clicking Edit, Save, Edit, Save, Edit, Save ... there will be 3 events (same events) binded. And will be triggered 3 times. Thats a memory leak. You need to remove that event when clicking Save button..."  
Just to confirm:  even though I do hide() and show(), the edit/save still triggers 3 times based on your example?

Comment: hiding buttons doesn't have anything to do with it, as you bind events to `td` element

Comment: Thank you again.  I really appreciate your help.  I will take a look at the rest, and be sure to follow up.

Comment: There is a method that allows you to bind event to every element that matches given selector, even when it was dynamically created after defining that event, but... that maybe on next lesson :D

Comment: When I tested it, the cost changes to $2.25. I did this: $("td:nth-child(2)").on("input",function(){ if ($(this).text() == "Tea" || "tea") { $(this).next("td").html("2.25"); } else if ($(this).text() == "Coke" || "coke") { $(this).next("td").html("2.50"); } else if ($(this).text() == "Coffee" || "coffee") { $(this).next("td").html("2.75"); } }); 

https://jsfiddle.net/9d7ee9fr/6/

Comment: If the cell wasn't next to each other but a few columns over: Do I do this:  $(this).next('td').next('td')..until I get to the right cell Professor? :)

Comment: Yes, you can do that or use something like `.nextAll('td:lt(2)')` <-- 2nd next

Comment: When I tested it, whatever drink I change to, the costs changes to $2.25 

For example, if I click edit, change the drink type from coke to coffee, the cost should be $2.75.  Instead, the cost changes to 2.25 (tea price)
I did this: $("td:nth-child(2)").on("input",function(){ if ($(this).text() == "Tea" || "tea") { $(this).next("td").html("2.25"); } else if ($(this).text() == "Coke" || "coke") { $(this).next("td").html("2.50"); } else if ($(this).text() == "Coffee" || "coffee") { $(this).next("td").html("2.75"); } }); 

JS Fiddle Link:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/9d7ee9fr/6)

Comment: I figured out why it did not work.  I should have never nested the 

    $("td:nth-child(2)").off('input');

in the editBtn function.  I fixed the code above, updated the js, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try and **run the code snippet.**
Logic used:

1. I used a **object array (key value) for drinkOptions** to
   initialize the select tag and placed it in a function.
2. Every time I click place order, I **append a table row with data-key attribute**
       (data-key=Tea, data-key=Coffee) to the tbody element. Think of the
       **data-key as the unique ID for drink**.
3. Every time I click save, I
   **loop through all the .receiptItem** elements inside tbody and check if
   it matches data-key. **If it matches data-key** then replace its value
   with my edited drink or price.

```js
// if errors JavaScript will stop running
"use strict";

// Global Variables
var amt = 0;
var itemNumber; // for receipt purposes

// declare drinkOptions as key value array
var drinkOptions = {
  "Tea": "2.25",
  "Coke": "2.5",
  "Coffee": "2.75"
};

var drink; //holds the drink
var price; //holds the price

function findNReplaceItem(key, nDrink, nPrice) {
  var found = false;
  alert("key:" + key);
  for (var i in drinkOptions) {
    if (i == nDrink) {
      //replace the value of drink in key value array with new price
      drinkOptions[i] = nPrice;
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // replace all drink cost
  $(".receiptItem").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("data-key") == key) {
      $(this).find("td").eq(1).html(nDrink);
      $(this).find("td").eq(2).html(nPrice)
    }
  });

  //replace the values from select drink type
  initializeSelect();
  return found;
}

function initializeSelect() {
  $("#drinkType").html("");
  $("#drinkType").append("<option value='#'>Select Drink</option>");
  $.each(drinkOptions, function(key, value) {
    $("#drinkType").append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + key + " $" + value + "</option>");
  });
}

//initialize select with drinkOptions
$(document).ready(function() {
  initializeSelect();
});

// ready event: short way
// long way: $(document).ready(function()){
$(function() {
  // calculates total cost
  $("#placeOrderBtn").click(function() {
    if ($("#drinkType").val() == "#") {
      alert("Please select a drink type");
    } else {
      drink = $("#drinkType").val(); // get the key, in this case Coffee or Tea or Coke

      //loop on drinkOptions and find key match
      $.each(drinkOptions, function(key, value) {
        if (drink == key) {
          price = value;

          $("tbody").append("<tr class='receiptItem' data-key='" + key + "'><td></td><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + value + "</td><td><input type='button' value='Edit' class='editBtn'><input type='button' value='Save' class='saveBtn'></td></tr>");
        }
      });
    }

    // edits information
    $(".editBtn").click(function() {
      $(this).hide(); // hides edit button
      $(this).parent().find(".saveBtn").show(); // displays save button

      // finding cells in the row of the selected edit button, but ignores last item
      $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function() {
        $("td:first-child").prop("contenteditable", false);
        $("tr").not(this).prop("contenteditable", false);
        $(this).prop("contenteditable", true);

        $("td:first-child, .editBt, saveBtn").css({
          "backgroundColor": "#fff"
        });
        $(this).css({
          "backgroundColor": "#c4c7c6"
        });

      });
    });
    // saves information
    $(".saveBtn").click(function() {

      //call function and pass arguments; data-key, drink type, drink price
      var row = $(this).parent().parent();
      if (findNReplaceItem(row.attr("data-key"), row.find("td:nth-child(2)").html(), row.find("td:nth-child(3)").html())) {

      } else {
        alert("Didn't find in drinkOptions!");
        $(this).eq(2).val("");
        $(this).eq(3).val("");
      }

      $(this).hide(); // hides save button
      $(this).parent().find(".editBtn").show(); // displays edit button
      $(this).prop("contenteditable", false);
      $("td").not(this).prop("contenteditable", false);

      $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function() {
        $(this).css({
          "backgroundColor": "#fff"
        });
      });

    });
  }); // end places order click

}); // end of ready event handler
```

```css
/* Removes all default margin and padding */

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 80%;
}

fieldset {
  border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: .5em;
  width: 400px;
}


/* Centering Customer's Info text */

legend,
label {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 .25em;
}

#placeOrderBtn {
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.hideReceiptBtn {
  display: none;
}

#receiptOrders tbody {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}


/* lists item number */

#receiptOrders tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}


/* displays item number */

#receiptOrders tbody tr td:first-child:before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
}

.saveBtn {
  display: none;
}

table,
th,
td {
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background-color: #dcedec;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: .2em;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: .3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>Sample</h1>
</header>

<div class="container">

  <main>

    <br>

    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>
          Customer's Information
        </legend>
        <br><br> Drink Order:
        <!--asks for coffee type-->
        <select name="drinkType" id="drinkType">
        <option value="#">Select Drink</option>
    </select>
        <br><br>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="placeOrderBtn" value="Place Order">
        <br><br>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <br>
    <h3 class="hiddenReceipt">Receipt</h3>
    <br>
    <table id="receiptOrders">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item Number</th>
          <th>Drink Type</th>
          <th>Drink Cost</th>
          <th>Edit/Save</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

  </main>

</div>
<!-- end .container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, when  I ran your code snippet, it didn't work. When I changed the drink type, the drink cost remains the same.

Comment: Ah, might need to put foreach another loop for that one hahaha